# CSS transition only working in one direction

Tags: css, css-transitions

does anybody know why the transition is working when I first click the button, then the text disappears after 2s. But it should also show up after 2sek when i click the button again after the text has been hidden. But when I click it, the text appears immediately.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Hit me</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title-bar">This is the title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container .title-bar {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 2s;
    transition: visibility 2s;
}

.container.fixed .title-bar {
  visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 2s;
    transition: visibility 2s;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  if ($('.container').hasClass('fixed')) {
    $('.container').removeClass('fixed');  
  } else {
    $('.container').addClass('fixed');  
  }
});
```

I created a pen for this:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqeNrW

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> visibility: if one of the values is visible, interpolated as a discrete step where values of the timing function between 0 and 1 map to visible and other values of the timing function (which occur only at the start/end of the transition or as a result of cubic-bezier() functions with Y values outside of [0, 1]) map to the closer endpoint; if neither value is visible then not interpolable.

So, the visibility is going , so to say, from 0 to 1, and in the intermediate steps will be some value between 0 and 1.

But, all the fractionary values are mapped to visible, and this produces the effect that you see.

Instead of the setting a transition-duration, set a transition-delay and it will work as expected

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  if ($('.container').hasClass('fixed')) {
    $('.container').removeClass('fixed');  
  } else {
    $('.container').addClass('fixed');  
  }
});
```

```css
.container .title-bar {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 2s;
 transition: visibility 0s 2s;
}

.container.fixed .title-bar {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Hit me</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title-bar">This is the title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```